# TRUE/FALSE outcome in R

Tags: r

I have following vectors:

```
A <- c(8.4, 9.5, 8.1)
B <- c(NA,NA,NA)
```

I wanted R to do the following: if in column A the values are less than 8.5  or  in column B values are less than 8 to write "TRUE", otherwise write "FALSE".

I tried the following:

```
C <- (A <8.5 | B <8)
```

I was expecting the following: TRUE, FALSE, TRUE

But the outcome was:

```
> C
# [1] TRUE   NA TRUE
```

Obviously when the R saw that A was not less than 8.5 in the second variable it went to B and when there was NA it wrote NA as an output.

Do you have any suggestions how I can avoid this?

Comment: It depends how you want to treat NA's. According to your expected output NA's should be treated as a big number. Maybe you can replace NA's with Inf and then perform your operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isTRUE`:

```
 isTRUE( FALSE | NA)
[1] FALSE
```

It is unwise to use "C" as a variable name because both "c" and "C" are (different) R functions. But with your example:

```
> sapply(C, isTRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `is.na` function to first determine whether B is `NA`, if it's set you can check if it's less than 8.

```
C <-(A < 8.5 | (!is.na(B) & B < 8) )
```